# Adjust the displayed part of a rose plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Does anyone know how to modify Matlab `rose` function to show only 
a range from 0 to `pi/2` (0-90º)?

I can't seem to find it anywhere. 
`xlim` and `ylim` don't seem to work

Comment: Yes, I only want 1/4 shown, or 1/2... not the whole circle (0-360º).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use the `XLim` and `YLim` properties of the parent `axes` to adjust the display such that it only shows the first quadrant.

```
hax = axes();
theta = [0.4 1.4 3.1 2.3 0.4 2.5 3.9 2.8 2.3 1.6 4.6 4.5 6.1 3.9 5.1];
rose(hax, theta, 10)

% Set the x and y limits to show only the first quadrant
hax.XLim = [0 hax.XLim(2)];
hax.YLim = [0 hax.YLim(2)];
```

[image]

If instead you want 0 to pi (180 degrees)

```
hax = axes();
rose(hax, theta, 10)

% Set only the y limits
hax.YLim = [0 hax.YLim(2)];
```

[image]